# Need to validate my understanding of how sed is editing this file

Tags: bash, sed

This is the file which is being edited by sed:

```
# cat flyway.conf.j2
flyway.url=jdbc:postgresql://{{ DB_HOST }}:5432/{{ DB_NAME }}?currentSchema=fm_fmp
flyway.user={{ FLYWAY_USER }}
flyway.password={{ FLYWAY_PASSWORD }}
```

This is the code snippet and the comments are my understanding of the code, is my understanding correct, also how is ##*/ getting the basename of the directory:

```
# To get the last dir in current working directory, and if you want to do it completely within a bash script without running any external binaries
SCHEMA=${PWD##*/}    
#sed -i means inplace, alnum means alphanumeric, 1s (Only search and replace 1st line) searching for string =any_alpha_numeric then _ then {}, 
    # then *$ meaning to the end and replace with value of variable $SCHEMA 
    sed -i "1s/=[[:alnum:]_{} ]*$/=${SCHEMA}/" flyway.conf.j2
```

Comment: The regex expects `alphanumeric`, `_`, `{` and `}` in any sequence in between `=` and the end of line. This will not modify line 1 of the input file because of `:`. If this expression is applied on line 2 or line 3, then it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${PWD##*/}` is part of bash variable expansion. Generally

> ${var##Pattern} Remove from $var the longest part of $Pattern that matches the front end of $var.

So it results in the current working directory, minus the first part of it which ends in `/`.
`[[:alnum:]_{} ]*` is a regular expression for "any number of letters digits, space, underscore or curly braces".
`$` requires the regex to end at the line and it has to start with a `=`.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful, we are doing the replacement after = only for first line, as we have different directories for different schemas.

Comment: Oh yes of course. You even correctly explained yourself already in the question. My mistake. Thanks for letting me know.